# Char array copy fails

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I'm copying an array, and for some reason the values aren't the same after the copy.  The code is below. In both cases, the _data variable is a char[4]. After the copy, the assert fires. If I examine the two values in the debugger, they show as: `0x00000000015700a8` and `0x00000000015700b0`.

```
_data[0] = rhsG->_data[0];

_data[1] = rhsG->_data[1];

_data[2] = rhsG->_data[2];

_data[3] = rhsG->_data[3];

assert(_data == rhsG->_data);
```

Comment: you are asserting on their address...not values. you can only assert `_data[0] == rhsG->_data[0]`.

Comment: Is this code in a copy constructor or assignment operator by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

You've made the mistake of thinking C++ is an easy-to-use high-level language (joke). `operator ==` on C-style arrays compares their address, which of course is different here. You can use `std::equal` to compare the two arrays, or use a different data structure which supports a more intuitive `opeartor ==`, such as `std::array` or `std::vector`.

You could then also use their `operator =` to copy them, instead of each element one at a time, assuming the source and destination are the same size. There is `std::copy` if they are not, or they must be C-style arrays.

Comment: C++ is a high level language as long as you don't go and muck with the C compatibility layer (antijoke)

Comment: Thanks. I knew this, I'm just a f**king idiot. It was late, what can I say.

Answer (score 2):

If comparing with == you are just comparing two pointers, which value are different. If you want to compare for equality two arrays, you can use memcmp()

```
assert( ! memcmp(_data, rhsG->_data, 4) );
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use operator == in assert "_data == rhsG->_data", _data and rhsG->_data are both represented address of the array. So, in your debugger, 0x00000000015700a8 is array address of _data and 0x00000000015700b0 is array address of rhsG->_data. Obviously, they are different, then the assert fires.
After all, array name is always a pointer that point to the first array address in memory.

Answer (score 1):

"`_data == rhsG->_data`" does not compare the individual elements of two arrays.

The "`==`" operator is not defined for arrays, so the two parameters are [decayed to **pointers**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying), which `==` **can** work on.

Answer (score 0):

Your assert is comparing the *addresses* of the two arrays which are different because they are in different memory locations.

If you really want to compare the values, then either loop over them or use [`memmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/).

```
assert(memcmp(_data, rhsG->_data, 4) == 0);
```